Chat GPT API - using in LARAVEL - PHP FRAMEWIORK
I`m using this api to translate audio to text:
the example code is
public function speechToText($filepath, $fileName)
{
    $audioFilePath = $filepath;
    $response = $this->media->request('POST', 'audio/translations', [
          'multipart' => [
            [
                'name' => 'model',
                'contents' => 'whisper-1',
                'timestamp_granularities' => 'word'
            ],
            [
                'name' => 'file',
                'contents' => fopen($audioFilePath, 'r'),
                'filename' => $fileName
            ]
        ]
    ]);

    $data = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents(), true);
    return $data
}

but its not return any used token
how do i calculate token for each translation

Did you look at the Documentation for this API that you dont tell us about?

Yes, SpeechtoText return only text as output. There is no calculation of Token, Actually need to calculate by using "words in a sentence". how to calculate ?

   public static function estimateTokens(string $text, string $method = "max"): int
    {
        $wordCount = str_word_count($text);
        $charCount = strlen($text);

        $wordEst = $wordCount / 0.75;
        $charEst = $charCount / 4.0;

        switch ($method) {
            case "average":
                $output = ($wordEst + $charEst) / 2;
                break;
            case "words":
                $output = $wordEst;
                break;
            case "chars":
                $output = $charEst;
                break;
            case "max":
                $output = max($wordEst, $charEst);
                break;
            case "min":
                $output = min($wordEst, $charEst);
                break;
            default:
                throw new InvalidArgumentException("Invalid method. Use 'average', 'words', 'chars', 'max', or 'min'.");
        }

        return (int) $output;
    }

by using this calculating Tokens

Please explain how this solved the issue. In the original question this function doesn't exists and/or get called. Where and how are you using this function?
